# Make JTable Column Header Not Movable/Resizable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Whatever I try I cannot get a JTable's header to be static. Right now you can click in the headers and drag them out or just relocate the entire columns of the table by moving the header.

Is there a way to prevent this and make the headers not editable?

Just to be clear I am not talking about the actual cells but the headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class JTableHeader has a method

```
setReorderingAllowed(boolean reorderingAllowed)
```

did you try that already, or does it maybe help you with your problem?

Comment: No, how would I use this?

Comment: I didn't really work with JTables myself yet, but something like
`nameOfYourTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false)` maybe? Or doesn't that work/change anything?